# How to hide wp-admin AWS NginX

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I have a wordpress site that I would like to restrict access to the admin page. The server sits in AWS behind an ELB. I am setting up the location directive in my .conf file between the server {}'s. The config that I have set is not working as I can still access the page from an ip address which should be denied.

Can someone please give a look and give some guidance? Thank you!

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin\.php) { 
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For; 
set_real_ip_from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; 
allow xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; 
deny all; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below for making your use case to work.

```
location ~ ^/(wp-admin|wp-login.php) {
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For; 
allow xx.xx.xx.xx;
deny all;
}
```